# find sold subscriptions from table 1 and store name in table 2, joined by store id. (oracle)

Tags: oracle, join, count

I am trying to get the number of sold subscriptions from one table and the store name from another. The tables have a common column containing a store id, however the columns do not have the same name.

```
Talbe1                  |   Table2

Amount     store_code   |   store_name    store_no

1          nf1ii        |   Jims kiosk    nf1ii
1          nfoi1        |   Henrys kiosk  nfoi1
...        ...          |   ...           ...
```

I am trying to count the number of subscriptions sold for each store name. How is this doen in Oracle? I am fairly new to SQL in general so please forgive me if the question is phrased strangely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a statement that should work and will also display the store when there are no subscriptions for that store in table2.

```
SELECT t2.store_no,
       t2.store_name,
       NVL(total_subs, 0) total_subs
  FROM Table2 t2,
       (SELECT store_code,
               COUNT(*) total_subs
          FROM table1
         WHERE subs = 'twin'
           AND sdate > TO_DATE('01.05.13','MM.DD.RR')
         GROUP BY store_code
       ) t1
 WHERE t2.store_no=t1.store_code (+)
```

It's also good practice when you're wanting to compare dates that you perform the date conversion explicitly, and don't rely on Oracle to do it for you. So in my example I used the Oracle TO_DATE function to make "01.05.13" into a date.  In your example the only way Oracle would know what format the date is in is if the NLS_DATE_FORMAT session variable is set to MM.DD.RR or DD.MM.RR.  If this session variable was changed, or you ran your code on a different Oracle instance whose NLS_DATE_FORMAT is different, then your code would fail.  I also changed the column name in my example to **sdate** since normally the word **date** can't be used as a column name unless it's enclosed in quotes (i.e. **"date"**).

Comment: Thank you i tried your code (and added trim() around the last statement because store_code had a trailing space in it.) worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
t2.store_name 
,t1.store_code
,sum (t1.Amount) -- if Amount can be >1
,count (t1.*)  -- if counting rows is enough and we want to show stores without subscribtions
from Table1 t1
right join Table2 t2 on t1.store_code=t2.store_code
where
t1.subs = 'twin' /* type of subscription */
and t1.date > '01.05.13'
group by t2.store_name, t1.store_code
```

It is a good practice to use LEFT JOIN rather then RIGHT JOIN, as the later one is harder to imagine and understand.

```
select 
t1.store_name 
,t2.store_code
,sum (t2.Amount) -- if Amount can be >1
,count (t2.*)  -- if counting rows is enough and we want to show stores without subscribtions
from Table2 t1
left join Table1 t2 on t1.store_code=t2.store_code
where
t2.subs = 'twin' /* type of subscription */
and t2.date > '01.05.13'
group by t1.store_name, t2.store_code
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. It was really usefull, we got it working at last. I think the problem with my original code was mainly that the store_code column had a trailing space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Working code i ended up using was:

```
select count(*) as Amount, d.store_name
from table1 sa
full outer join table2 d on trim( sa.store_code )=d.store_no
where
sa.soc = 'TWIN'
and sa.date > '01.05.2013'
group by d.store_name
order by Amount desc;
```

the column store_code gave me some trouble due to trailing spaces in that column and not in the store_no column. This caused the match to fail.